# Cache multiple pages/images from Instagram

Tags: php, caching, instagram

I'm working on a small project where the users can see images taged by, in this case, "kitties". Instagram only allows 5000 requests/hour, i don't think it will reach this, but i'm choosing to cache any way. Also because i can't figure out how to get the back-link to work. 
I can only get the link for next page, then the link for recent page becomes the current page, a link to itself.
Also, the api can return strange number of images, some times 14, some times 20 and so on. I want it to always show 20 images per page and only have 5 pages (100 images). And then update this file each 5/10 minutes or something.

So, my plan is to store like 100 images into a file. I got it working, but it's incredible slow.
The code looks like this:

```
$cachefile = "instagram_cache/".TAG.".cache";
$num_requests = 0; //Just for developing and check how many request it does

//If the file does not exsists or is older than *UPDATE_CACHE_TIME* seconds
if (!file_exists($cachefile) || time()-filemtime($cachefile) > UPDATE_CACHE_TIME)
{
    $images = array();
    $current_file = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/".TAG."/media/recent?client_id=".INSTAGRAM_CLIENT_ID;
    $current_image_index = 0;


    for($i = 0; $i >= 0; $i++)
    {
        //Get data from API
        $contents = file_get_contents($current_file);

        $num_requests++;
        //Decode it!
        $json = json_decode($contents, true);

        //Get what we want!
        foreach ($json["data"] as $x => $value)
        {                
            array_push($images, array(
                'img_nr' => $current_image_index,
                'thumb' => $value["images"]["thumbnail"]["url"],
                'fullsize' => $value["images"]["standard_resolution"]["url"],
                'link' => $value["link"], 
                'time' => date("d M", $value["created_time"]),
                'nick' => $value["user"]["username"],
                'avatar' => $value["user"]["profile_picture"],
                'text' => $value['caption']['text'],
                'likes' => $value['likes']['count'],
                'comments' => $value['comments']['data'],
                'num_comments' => $value['comments']['count'],
            ));

            //Check if the requested amount of images is equal or more...
            if($current_image_index > MAXIMUM_IMAGES_TO_GET)
                break;

            $current_image_index++;

        }
        //Check if the requested amount of images is equal or more, even in this loop...
        if($current_image_index > MAXIMUM_IMAGES_TO_GET)
            break;
        if($json['pagination']['next_url'])
            $current_file = $json['pagination']['next_url'];

        else
            break; //No more files to get!

    }
    file_put_contents($cachefile, json_encode($images));
```

This feels like a very ugly hack, any ideas for how to make this work better?

Or someone that can tell me how to make that "back-link" to work like it should? (Yes, i could yes js and go -1 in history, but no!).

Any ideas, suggestions, help, comments etc are appreciated.

Comment: Having this same problem Gubbfett and implementing a similar solution as Instagram seems to have so many damn limitations in place with regards to requests per hour, not allowing multi tag searches, and maxiumum images per request etc. Have you worked out why this was so slow as I would think reading json directly off the disk would be super fast and the only delay would be rendering the images to the screen?

Comment: Well, the thing that was slow was to grab images, when the images finally was collected it was no problem getting them. I how ever made some changes and set up a mysql db to store the images and then runs that file as a cron every 5 minutes. It was faster and more reliable, and if the cron is running, the users can still get images since it's not writing to a file in that moment. Another workaround i tested for the 5000 imgaes / hour was just to create multiple accounts the the app and have a controller that changes id-number for every search. ;)

Comment: Yep i have done something similar and it's working really well especially with the requirement to have multiple tag searching as I can now search the cached JSON files direct which contain a list of all tags per media item in the results. The only trick is how to get as many results as possible (ie.100+) sitting in the cached results at all times as Instagram only lets me grab 30 at a time. I was going to try using the paging options to try and pull back more using a CRON job in the background. I love the idea of multiple accounts being used to switch the ID's very clever :)

Comment: Oh, so you cache every "page" of images as separated files? I thought of that, but it felt like it was a risk to get some duplicates then. My final solution was to make a loop like above, with a maximum of say 400 pages. this every 5 minutes is like 4800 requests/hour. Then, if there's no next page i just delete it. Then i make an insert for each image to the DB with a "on duplicate key update" with the image id as key. Problem with this is that the oldest files (over 400 pages away) does not get their comments updated. but i do not really care about that since it will never reach 400 ;)

Comment: No i only cache the requests, so every single search keyword would be a separate cache file, along with getMedia operations as well. The only thing i don't cache is obviously POST operations such as LIKE and Authenticate. Okay so basically you just loop over the same process grabbing as many images as you can within the 5000 limit and  keeping that cache file up to date every 5 minutes. So every live request to Instagram is done via your CRON job, and all front-end requests are done direct to cache. I like it.

Comment: Also with the paging next_min_id, next_max_id is there a way to call the next 20-30 results or do you have to base the paging off these max/min params in the previous request?

Comment: Not really sure about the question, but i do like this; When i run the cron it starts at the "first page", collects the images, if there's a 'next_url' and the loop index is < 400, i load the images from that page and repeats this until the loop index == 400 or the next_url is blank. So i never look into next_min/max_id, i just go for the next_url :)

Comment: And i don't know if this is a good solution for a site where there's a lots of images and it's hundreds of pages and stuff. I do it this way (the on duplicate->update) just for the comments. If there would be no comments i would also check if the image id already exsists and then exit the loop if it does. One problem with this tho is that if a user deletes a image it still remains in the DB and it can't show it. So i check if the image exsists before i print it and if does not, i just skip to show this one. This site is just temporary so i have not really worked on this solution.

Comment: Please post your solution when you're done. Would be cool to see how you solved it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not subscribe to real-time and store the images in the DB? Then, when they are rendered you can check if the image url is valid (check if the photo has been deleted). Getting the data from your own DB will be much faster than from instagram